# Return the first row if duplicate exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Note I always want to return all columns and not only those that are defined as distinct
I have a table lets call it Foo with these columns DeviceId, TransactionId, IndetId, Datetime, SalesId, and Quantity and some more columns

If I have rows that are identical for columns DeviceId, TransactionId, IndetId, Datetime, SalesId I want to select only the first row and skip the rest.
An example
DeviceId TransactionId IndetId  Datetime SalesId Quantity
123      10              8     2022-12-12   700    45
123      10              8     2022-12-12   700    75
In this example only the first row should be returned.
I can't use a simple distinct because I need all columns to be returned

I had hoped that the syntax for doing this should be something like this. Telling sql to use distinct only on these columns.
SELECT distinct(DeviceId, TransactionId, IndetId,Datetime, SalesId), Quantity
FROM Foo

If I do SELECT distinctDeviceId, TransactionId, IndetId, Datetime, SalesId
FROM Foo
then I miss a lot of columns and the result will be wrong

Comment: Although you could use a CTE with a windowing function to return a single row with the same values in the four columns, the row returned will be arbitrary when the remaining columns differ. The key point is there is no first or last in a relational database table, which is an unordered set of rows.

Comment: _"SELECT distinctDeviceId, ..."_ looks like a missing-space typo (after the `distinct`)? And you can use back-ticks to format the SQL code differently than the question text